# How can I change the perspective of an object Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

I have a flat object.

I want to fit it on a laptop screen.  I can't use the perspective grid because it only deals with a straight line axis and the screen doesn't have any edges on a straight line.

I can't find a way to rotate or skew the perspective grid.

If I skew the object it doesn't work as I need to make each corner skew independently.

In Photoshop I can use Transform > Perspective.  Does Illustrator CS5 have a similar function?

I want to put the recycling symbol on all three screens.  What's the easiest way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Illustrator **CS5** have a similar function?

Yes. But it's sort of hidden in CS5....

---

## For Illustrator CS6 or older....

Select an object and grab the **Free Transform Tool**

[image]

Now.. **in this order**.. you **must** follow this order....

1. Click a corner handle (but do **not** move the handle)
2. Hold down the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys
3. Drag the handle

This will create a Perspective Distortion on the object as you drag.

Again, this **only** works if you follow the **specific order** of steps above using the **Free Transform Tool**. This *won't* work with the standard bounding box or any other tool.

This is a CS6 animation, which is as close to CS5 as I can get on my systems.

[image]

---

## For Illustrator CC versions

The **Free Transform Tool** (e)

[image]

If you click the tool, you are presented with a popup tool bar... Perspective Distort is on that popup...

[image]

Click the **Perspective Distort Tool** and then click-drag a corner handle on the object you wish to distort.

-- The shortcut posted above for older versions will also still work in any newer version of Illustrator -- and the order of the steps still must be followed.

---

Be aware you **can not** distort linked/embedded *raster images* with this. These tools/shortcuts only work with native vector objects and/or groups. To distort linked/embedded raster images, see Andrew's method in the other answer.

Comment: That does not work for me.  All that happens is the object grows/shrinks in proportion with all sides shrinking from the centre not the point I click.  I don't seem to be able to select a corner which mayb be what I'm doing wrong.  If I hover on a corner it always has the resize too.

Comment: Sometime I can make the white dot appear as if you are able to select that corner using CTRL but when I drag it I see a new cursor icon which has a cursor and a no entry sign.

Comment: The order of the steps is **very** important. You cant move **at all** between clicking a handle and holding down the shortcut keys. It is **very** finicky.. but I assure you it does work. And by "corner" I mean the **bounding box of the free transform tool**.

Comment: Ah I see, great explanation thanks.  However, although I see the perspective changing, when I release the object stays flat.  Is there only certain file times you can do this with?  e.g. not a placed file?

Comment: That was indeed the case.  I needed to copy and paste the original vector into my file.  Thank you.  Very helpful.

Comment: @Eoin You should mark this post as resolved

Answer (score 2):

1) Draw a square on the screen with the same perspective as the screen. Make sure the square object is above the image in the layers panel.

[image: perspective square]

2) Select both the object and image.

3) Go to Object -> Envelope Distort -> Make with Top Object. Repeat for the other screens.

[image: final result]

Comment: Interesting, will try this too.